# Set the value of a field in a model as the value of a field in another model in django

Tags: python, django

I have a two model field one which is the user model and one which is the landlord model. I want the first_name and last_name of the user model to be saved also in the landlord model.

This is my model view

````
  pass

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nin = models.IntegerField(unique = True , null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null= True, default="avatar.svg")

    objects = UserManager()

class Landlord(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True , null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    nin = models.IntegerField(unique = True , null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null= True, default="avatar.svg")
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS= []
   
    objects = User()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)```
````

Comment: The modeling does not seem to make much sense: your `LandLord` model seems to be a "user model" as well, and uses `User()` as `objects`? Furthermore why save this a second time, and not just fetch it from the user when needed? By duplicating data, you make it harder to keep the data consistent.

Comment: Okay, how can i fetch it? Kindly help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating such model decide to do one of solutions:

1. Inherit from `User` model:

   ```
   class Landlord(User):
   ```
2. Make User universal model with a flag if it is a `Landlord` user:

   ```
   class User(AbstractUser):
       ...
       is_landlord = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   ```

With option 2 just everywhere you need only `Landlord` things use `if user.is_landlord:` or in templates: `{% if user.is_landlord %}` etc.

Comment: It isn't working still.

Comment: @SirFeranmi What do you mean "it is not working"? I've served you alternative ways of serving data. "Copying" fields from one model to another is a redundant behaviour and I strongly advise choosing one of that ways. It's not solution to copy fields values.

Comment: So sorry for the inconvenience,  {% if user.is_landlord %} works if the user is a landlord. What is the if tag for non-landlord

Comment: {% if not user.is_landlord %}

Comment: This worked! Thank you sir. How will I  get is_landlord details like first_name, last_name in a template even if no user is logged in

Comment: @SirFeranmi ask another question, don't chat in comments, please, because here it does not have a good context and I really don't understand where you have a problem with that.